# Why dereferencing a NSString pointer is not necessary?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring

In the example

```
NSString *message = @"Hello";
message = @"World";
```

If message is just a pointer why don't I need to explicitly say whatever is in message is now equal to string or `*message = @"World";` like in C?

Comment: because `@"World"` gives address of the string literal. as `message=&...`

Comment: `@"Hello"` is conceptually a shortcut for `[[[NSString alloc] initWithUtf8String:"Hello"]] autorelease]`.

Comment: ...because @"World" is also a pointer? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**

The discussion below gives a general idea on why you never dereferenciate a pointer to an object in Objective-C.
However, concerning the specific case of `NSString` literals, this is not what's happening in reality. While the structure described below is still sound and it may work that way, what's actually happening is that the space for a string literal is allocated at compile time, and you get its address back. This is true for string literals, since they are immutable and constant. For the sake of efficiency therefore each literal is allocated only once.

As a matter of fact

```
NSString * a = @"Hello";
NSString * b = @"Hello";
NSLog(@"%@ %p", a, a); // Hello 0x1f4958
NSLog(@"%@ %p", b, b); // Hello 0x1f4958
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Because it will be translated to

```
message = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"Hello"]];
```

which will boil down to

```
message = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSString"), @selector(alloc)), @selector(initWithUTF8String:), "Hello");
```

Now if we take a look to the signature of `objc_msgSend`

```
id objc_msgSend(id theReceiver, SEL theSelector, ...)
```

we see that the method returns an `id` type, which in Objective-C is the object type. But how is `id` actually defined?

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

`id` is defined as a pointer to an `objc_object` struct.

So in the end `@"string"` will translate in a function call that will produce a pointer to an object (i.e. an `objc_object` struct, if you prefer), which is exactly what you need to assign to `message`.

Bottom line, **you assign pointers, not objects**.

To better clarify the last concept consider this

```
NSMutableString * a = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello"];
NSMutableString * b = a;
[a setString:@"hola"];
NSLog(@"%@", a); // "hola"
NSLog(@"%@", b); // "hola"
```

If you were assigning objects, `b` would have been a copy of `a` and any further modification of `a` wouldn't have affected `b`.

Instead what you get is `a` and `b` being two pointers to the same object in the heap.

Comment: I liked your bottom line. make it bold... so that I can give you +1 :)

Comment: It deserves a bold, indeed.

Comment: String literals like `@"Hello"` are compiled into the binary, they are not translated to `alloc:initWithUTF8String`.

Comment: @MartinR yes you're are right, since that's a special case for optimizing string literals. That said, the rest of the discussion is still relevant. I'll add a note.

Comment: iirc isn't possible to store an object on the stack, allowing yourself to eliminate the pointer? (I remember that when objective c was young you could manage to do this, not sure about nowadays) Now why you would want to do this? I have no idea... :P

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to allocate "normal" objects on the stack. Blocks are an exception, but I'm not aware of others.

Comment: You can definitely just place a `objc_object` on the stack and copy stuff in. Note that if you're going to do something like an NSString you'll need to create your own struct with all the proper members then. But as soon as you want to do anything with that NSString you'll have to reference that struct. So all in all irrelevant

Comment: @DanZimm Yeah what I meant is to stick to the regular object lifecycle. Clearly in the end this is just C, therefore you can easily have any struct on the stack. However I hardly doubt than any of the API will work on that object ;)

Comment: *makes an api strictly for stack objects* ;D